# Lightning Component in Flow Screen using IE11

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-components, ie-11

I'm using a lightning component in a screen flow, in chrome it works, but not in IE11.

Anyone has any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

> IMPORTANT Support for Internet Explorer 11 to access Lightning Experience is retiring beginning in Summer ’16.
>   You can continue to use IE11 to access Lightning Experience until December 16, 2017.
>   If you opt in to Extended Support for IE11, you can continue to use IE11 to access Lightning Experience until December 31, 2020.
>   IE11 has significant performance issues in Lightning Experience.
>   It is strongly recommended that you do not use Internet Explorer 11 with Community Builder.
>   This change doesn’t impact Salesforce Classic.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm

> Aura Components support the same browsers as Lightning Experience.

So, it is better not to consider IE11 at all.

Comment: I did activate the opt for supporting IE11, and nothing is changed, the lightning component doesn't work in the flow.